# Java Open HttpsUrlConnection with pfx Certificate

Tags: java, ssl, https, certificate

I am trying to connect to a secure web server programmatically.  I have the pfx certificate used to access the server and can access it via the browser.  However I get the following error:

java.security.cert.CertificateException: No subject alternative names present

This code I am using:

```
KeyStore keyStore = KeyStore.getInstance("PKCS12");
keyStore.load(new FileInputStream("path/to/pfxFile"), "mypassword");
KeyManagerFactory keyManagerFactory = KeyManagerFactory
                .getInstance(KeyManagerFactory.getDefaultAlgorithm());
keyManagerFactory.init(keyStore, "mypassword");

KeyStore trustStore = KeyStore.getInstance("JKS");
trustStore.load(new FileInputStream("path/to/cacerts"), "changeit");
TrustManagerFactory trustManagerFactory = TrustManagerFactory
                .getInstance(TrustManagerFactory.getDefaultAlgorithm());
trustManagerFactory.init(trustStore);

SSLContext sslContext = SSLContext.getInstance("TLS");
sslContext.init(keyManagerFactory.getKeyManagers(), trustManagerFactory.getTrustManagers(),
                new SecureRandom());

URL url = new URL("https://XXX.XXX.XXX.XXX/MyWebService");
connection = (HttpsURLConnection) url.openConnection();
connection.setSSLSocketFactory(sslContext.getSocketFactory());
connection.setRequestProperty("Content-Type", "text/xml");
connection.setRequestMethod("GET");
connection.setConnectTimeout(120000);
connection.connect();
```

I managed to find a workaround for that error by putting the following directly before the openConnection call:

```
HttpsURLConnection.setDefaultHostnameVerifier((hostname, session) -> hostname.equals("XXX.XXX.XXX.XXX"));
```

Only to give me:

javax.net.ssl.SSLHandshakeException: sun.security.validator.ValidatorException: PKIX path building failed: sun.security.provider.certpath.SunCertPathBuilderException: unable to find valid certification path to requested target

I couldn't find any resolutions for this issue.  I've tried exporting the cert and adding it to cacert via keytool, but it doesn't help and I'm out of ideas. Any help is appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So it turns out I just needed to download the server cert and add that to cacerts instead of using the pkcs12 file.